# Creating bash alias that starts two processes?

Tags: macos, bash, alias

I would like to create an alias that:

1. changes directories
2. starts redis
3. starts a node application

I was able to do this by creating an alias like the one below:

```
alias startSP='cd mydirectory; redis-server;node myApp.js'
```

The issue is that the `node myApp.js` pieces doesn't run until I kill redis.  Is there some way that I can start two processes without waiting for the first to finish?

Should I be trying to open a second tab to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a way to test this, but adding the '&' to run cmd in background should work, i.e.

```
 alias startSP='cd mydirectory ; redis-server & node myApp.js'
```

You will probably want to add a 2nd &, ie

```
 alias startSP='cd mydirectory ;redis-server & node myApp.js &'
```

As this will return the prompt to you and you can keep working at your commandline.

**edit**

There are many ways to kill processes, search here on S.O. If you lucky, you'll be able to do

```
   pkill redis-server
   pkill node ...? hm....
```

There are a lot of ways to get this wrong, so you'll do better to examine your particular case.

- Are there other copies of redis-server running that you DON'T want to kill?
- Are there other copies of node running AND then, how do you differniate those.
- How do you make sure you're killing the 'myApp.js' version of node.

If I was going to do this all the time, I would turn `startPS` into a function that captured the PIDs returned from using the '&', saved those pids to the environment, and then had a seperate function that could confirm those PIDs existed, AND that they had a high probability of being the correct program, THEN issue the kill.

Note also, that `kill -15` is the preferred way to kill a program, giving it the chance to close files, etc.

IHTH.

Comment: Awesome! How would I kill the processes when I'm done if I return to the command line?

Comment: @AbeMiessler : see my edit. You'll find plenty of discussion here on S.O. for portable ways to kill apps VS quick-and-dirty methods.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `;`, which separates two processes sequentially, you might use `&`, which starts one process in the background and then runs the other in the foreground:

```
alias startSP='cd mydirectory ; redis-server & node myApp.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a function to your profile instead?

```
startSP(){
 cd /your/directory
  redis-server && node myApp.js
```

}

The && will start make node myApp.js wait for the redis-server to start

Comment: What would be the benefit of doing this over using an alias?